# How to mass merge videos with multipliable audio tracks down into one track?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, batch

I have a few videos I want to upload to YouTube but it turns out YouTube uses it first audio track which is completely quiet.

I have one for VOIP, Desktop Sounds etc but **I want them all merged into one per-video file**. I looked into a few questions and each one of them only deals with either extracting audio or instead merging all tracks into one.

I'm no wizard with command line or FFmpeg so I'm clueless where to start.

**The formats are varied but all were recorded with OBS**

- mkv
- mp4
- mov

I see also that most output the file into new folder however most of my files are large and I'd probably run out of space so if I can safely replace the original I would do that however I'd rather keep my data.

I can use the Windows Bash Subsystem or Windows.

Comment: I've found some information about mixing channels down here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45826867/3340763

Comment: did you try some video edit software like adobe premiere pro, sony vegas or even some free ones. They allow you to merge multiple audio tracks into 1 channel. I do it all the time using sony vegas

Comment: I can, but that requires me to open it, then export it and hope it doesn't crash manually for about 1900 (most video files are only a few minutes long or shorter though some are hours long) files when I'd rather set a batch file and forget about it for a day or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ffmpeg` with the [amerge filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -ac 2 output.mp4
```

- Adjust the `inputs` value to the number of audio streams contained in the input. See an [example to script this using `ffprobe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45826867/1109017).
- `ffmpeg` must output a new file: it cannot replace the input.
- The video will be stream copied and not re-encoded.

Comment: Yes I saw this post but honestly was completely confused by what any of it did. I know all of the tracks have the same number of audio streams (at least they should even if a few don't have anything on them) In the case they fail what happens?

Comment: @Codingale If you give it an input where the number of audio streams is < the `inputs` value then you'll get an error: `Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 2 on filter Parsed_amerge_0`. If you give it an input where the number of audio streams is > the `inputs` value then it will ignore the additional, unaccounted stream(s) but an output will still be created.

Comment: So I'd be able to change `-i somefile.ext` `-filter_complex "[0:a]amerge=inputs=4[a]"` (assuming I have a max of 4 channels) and have the output instead be like `output.ext` I checked they're all the same format and information just different file containers. Then again you said it doesn't even mess with the video just audio.

Comment: Oh, I misread your comment, is there a way to ignore the error and keep going if the input audio streams are > the amerge `input`? I didn't know it'd halt as I thought the cases were swapped.

Comment: @Codingale The answer is yes for the first previous comment, but `inputs` does not refer to the number of channels: it is the number of individual audio streams ("tracks") within the input, and video will just be copied. The error received if the number of audio streams is less than the `inputs` value is considered to be "fatal" and that particular command process will fail. However, it is up to your scripting environment whether to proceed to the next command if you are using a loop to process multiple files. Error can be avoided with `ffprobe` to determine `inputs` as previously mentioned.

Comment: Yes. I've since made a script to probe and concatnate the tracks down and so far it seems to be doing well. I doubt but would be using GPU acceleration help or is it literally just coping the video over and adding the new audio what's taking so long for > 1 hour videos?

Comment: @Codingale Correct, GPU acceleration will do nothing helpful here. I'm not sure why it's taking so long–I would need to see your actual, unscripted command and the complete console output. You can use a pastebin site and provide a link in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Video LAN?

https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Merge_videos_together/

Comment: This merges all the files into one... which is not what I want.